# how to use the function in Fenics?

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I have the following question about using Fenics, namely how can I correctly use the function "**as_tensor**", "**as_vector**" and "**dot**"? what are the **original codes** for each function (how to open it) ?

e.g. if the input is **as_tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])**, what is the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation can be found here: https://fenicsproject.org/docs/ufl/1.5.0/ufl.html#ufl.tensors.as_tensor

and the source code at https://github.com/FEniCS/ufl/blob/master/ufl/tensors.py#L219